# How can I insert an iframe that cannot be interacted with him?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Good morning everyone, I want to insert an iframe from a Google Drive document, but I want it to be displayed only in view (they can't edit the document), they can only scroll

I researched on MDN about the iframe properties and I didn't find any answer

Thanks for answers!

Comment: This isn't something you configure with iframe properties. This would be a parameter to the Google Drive URL, to tell it to return a read-only document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have security concerns and just want make the iframe content readonly, simply apply:

```
iframe {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```